# Cancel file upload (retrofit) started from coroutine kotlin android

Tags: android, networking, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm trying to get rid of RxJava2 in my project and replace it with kotlin coroutines. 90% of my RxJava code is no longer exists but I still can`t replace one network request.
User can send photo to backend in my App (multipart form data request using retrofit). User also can cancel photo upload if it was not loaded yet. With RxJava I was able to keep Disposable object of upload request and if it is not disposed yet I could dispose it if user clicked cancel upload button. As result of this action network request was canceled too. So we could save some user traffic and battery.
Is it possible to achieve same logic with kotlin coroutines? In official docs written that coroutines cancellation is cooperative and we need some suspending function in loop (or in between file parts send) in order to stop coroutine.
So is this the case when RxJava is better choice or did I missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using retrofit for your network calls, you can add their coroutines call adapter from [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter).

You cancel a coroutine's running part by cancelling it's job. For example if you are using `launch` to launch your coroutine, it returns a `Job` object which can be cancelled.

```
val job = launch {
        repeat(1000) { i ->
            println("I'm sleeping $i ...")
            delay(500L)
        }
    }
    delay(1300L) // delay a bit
    println("main: I'm tired of waiting!")
    job.cancel() // cancels the job
    job.join() // waits for job's completion 
    println("main: Now I can quit.")
```

If you are not using retrofit and using another library, you can retrieve `isActive` inside you coroutine and cancel the request from your library.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking<Unit> {
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val job = launch {
        var nextPrintTime = startTime
        var i = 0
        while (isActive) { // cancellable computation loop
            // print a message twice a second
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= nextPrintTime) {
                println("I'm sleeping ${i++} ...")
                nextPrintTime += 500L
            }
        }
    }
    delay(1300L) // delay a bit
    println("main: I'm tired of waiting!")
    job.cancelAndJoin() // cancels the job and waits for its completion
    println("main: Now I can quit.")
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Coroutine call adapter is exactly what I need! But as of second part of answer (about isActive): I think it will not work. Because I do not have any loop or other place where I can check isActive property of coroutine. Retrofit handles part by part file upload by itself and I did not found any callbacks that could give a chance to check isActive while uploading is in progress. Anyway thanks once again!

Comment: No problem! are you sure that retrofit does not cancel the OkHttp request call? I don't see a difference here between rx and coroutine, so if the cancellation (the dispose in rx) works, it should work in coroutines too.

Comment: Yes, I checked twice. Cancelation of coroutine does not canel Retrofit upload request. The difference between rx and coroutine is exact in retrofit call adapter. Disposable that i use to cancel retrofit request was created by retrofit rxjava call adapter. That is why this disposable have impact on retrofit request. You can see it here: [link](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2/src/main/java/retrofit2/adapter/rxjava2/CallEnqueueObservable.java). `public void dispose()` method have `call.cancel` row. Same thing coroutine call adapter do.

Comment: That is weird, because it does cancel the download side. Maybe you could file an issue to the adapter repository. Although their repository is already stating that it is an experimental feature so I wouldn't be surprised If they add it in a future release. Also I don't think it would be that hard to create your own. You can convert the code from the Rx one to the 'coroutine' style. Anyways, Good luck!

Comment: Is there another way to cancel the retrofit request without "Kotlin Coroutine Adapter"?