# Cancel Retrofit request started from ViewModel coroutine job

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, viewmodel, coroutine

I would like my app users to be able to cancel file upload.

My coroutine upload job in ViewModel looks like this

```
private var uploadImageJob: Job? = null
private val _uploadResult = MutableLiveData<Result<Image>>()
val uploadResult: LiveData<Result<Image>>
    get() = _uploadResult

fun uploadImage(filePath: String, listener: ProgressRequestBody.UploadCallbacks) {
    //...
    uploadImageJob = viewModelScope.launch {
        _uploadResult.value = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.uploadImage(filePart)
        }
    }
}

fun cancelImageUpload() {
    uploadImageJob?.cancel()
}
```

Then in the repository the Retrofit 2 request is handled like this

```
suspend fun uploadImage(file: MultipartBody.Part): Result<Image> {
    return try {
        val response = webservice.uploadImage(file).awaitResponse()
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            Result.Success(response.body()!!)
        } else {
            Result.Error(response.message(), null)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Result.Error(e.message.orEmpty(), e)
    }
}
```

When `cancelImageUpload()` it called the job gets cancelled and the exception gets caught in the repository but the result won't get assigned to `uploadResult.value`.

Any ideas please how to make this work?

PS: There is a similar question [Cancel file upload (retrofit) started from coroutine kotlin android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50552373/cancel-file-upload-retrofit-started-from-coroutine-kotlin-android) but it suggests using `coroutines call adapter` which is depricated now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have finally managed to make it work by moving `withContext` one level up like this

```
uploadImageJob = viewModelScope.launch {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        _uploadResult.postValue(repository.uploadImage(filePart))
    }
}
```